# How can I fadeIn and fadeOut a div after a certain amount of time HTML / CSS

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have this one div that contains text  and then after a certain amount of time I want that div to fade out then another div fades in. I have tried this and the second div does not fade in:

```js
  $(function() {
    $(".preload").fadeOut(20, function() {
        $(".content").fadeIn(20);        
    });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="preload">
    <h1>1st page</h1>
   
</div>

<div class="content">
<h1>2nd page </h1>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the `.content` div to `display:none` initially and `fadeIn` once the `.preload` is set to `fadeOut()`

Also the `seconds` you have added are too `low` for div to show its `fadeIn` or `fadeOut` effect. At least use `2000` equivalent to `2` seconds fadeOut effects.

**Live Demo:**

```js
$(function() {
  $(".preload").fadeOut(2000, function() {
    $(".content").fadeIn(2000);
  });
});
```

```css
.content {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>First page </title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="preload">
    <h1>1st page</h1>

  </div>

  <div class="content">
    <h1>2nd page </h1>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: you really stay true to your title ahaha thank you so much. What I initially was trying to do was make a progress bar and either after like a certain amount of time or when the progress bar hits 100 to go to another webpage. However now with this, I can just have the 1st page contents in a div and the second-page contents in another div and then do what you did above. Thanks again

Comment: @kayacancode Glad to hear that :) Always happy to help and happy coding!